# xamarin forms ios InAppBillingPlugin subscription - Cannot connect to itunes store error

Tags: ios, xamarin, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, in-app-billing

I am using the InAppBillingPlugn https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/InAppBillingPlugin/PurchaseSubscription.html

I have cut and pasted the code for the subscription part from the above link and replaced my in app purchases info in the applicable places,etc.

The app is released in the app store and if there are any exceptions running the subscription code I log it to my database and I also log successful purchases to my database.

I am seeing over 95% of the entries are exceptions with the following exception 'Cannot connect to itunes store', while ~5% of the subscriptions succeed.

Does anybody know why the failure rate is so high? I don't know if it is an issue with the inappbilling, Apple, or the users?

Initially I thought it could be a localization issue, but I don't think that is it. I have a question to apple support but haven't heard back from them yet.

I have also read other threads with this same type of error, but it was usually around testing or the subscription wasn't setup. I have verified the subscription works there just seems to be a very high failure rate with users.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Are there any stack traces that indicate the issue?

Comment: No, I can work on a new release today that also saves the stack trace to the database

Comment: Just an fyi, I discovered if the user cancels from the apple confirm subscription dialog this will cause the "cannot connect to itunes.." error. So this could be my whole problem but it still seems odd such a high percentage of users would be cancelling after clicking subscribe, especially since I display the subscription price on the butto

Comment: Maybe they just wanted to see for shits and giggles what would happen if they press the button.

Comment: Not sure if it's related but my app is in review and it keeps getting this error too